# How to programmatically create a Kafka 2.3.0 topic in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to create a topic in Kafka (2.12-2) with Java API , i tried the old codes but they don't work for me any one can help me ?
i need to create a topic  and then i would like to insert it into the producer and a consumer

Comment: this one didn't work for me maybe the reason is the version of Kafka api

Comment: there are multiple answer for each version under that post, have you tried everything?

Comment: no, till now  just the second one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this one?

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");

AdminClient adminClient = KafkaAdminClient.create(props);

CreateTopicsResult res = adminClient.createTopics(
        Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz").map(
                name -> new NewTopic("my-topic-name", 3, (short) 1)
        ).collect(Collectors.toList())
);

res.all().get();
```

Comment: Properties props  = new Properties();  after this i can't  find  put() method ??

Comment: @medidriss What do you mean? Have you imported `Properties`?

Comment: yeah ,  but  i solve it by using Map for the config

Comment: yes thank you @Giorgos Myrianthous